# binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type NSDictionary and String in swift 3

Tags: swift

```
let contributor:NSDictionary! = (userProfile["Contributor"] as? NSDictionary)

    var contributorid:String!

    if contributor == nil || contributor == " "{

        contributorid = nil
    }
    else
    {
        contributorid = contributor.value(forKey: "id") as? String
    }
```

The above code was in swift 2.0  and after converting to swift 3 i'm getting error in 'if' condition as binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type NSDictionary and String    Please help me to find the solution.... Thanks

Comment: well if it's an `NSDictionary`, why are you comparing to a string? Why are you comparing something you just confirmed to be `nil` to `" "`?

Comment: You can use equality operator for the same kind of objects only.

Comment: the above code is working fine in swift 2.  but how  ?

Comment: *You cannot compare apples* (Dictionary) *with oranges* (String). Even if the code was working in Swift 2 the condition `contributor == nil && contributor == " "` is nonsense. It will never evaluate to true.

Comment: not sure why downvote. There is nothing wrong with this question. Just confused about how swift works.

Comment: there is a change in if condition..  that is not && operator, its || operator,  sorry for mistake

Comment: @Chanakya The problem is not with operator `&&` and `||` it is with `contributor == " "` here you are comparing dictionary to string that is the reason you are getting that error.

Comment: ok. Thanks @NiravD and all for the solution

Comment: @Chanakya Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The above code will also not work in Swift 2**, as of you are comparing `NSDictionary` and `String`, also in Swift use native type `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary` and you can use `guard let` and `if let` to wrapped the optional.

```
var contributorid: String? = nil
if let contributor = userProfile["Contributor"] as? [String:Any],
   let id = contributor["id"] as? String {

     contributorid = id
}
```